# installing ruby 1.8.7 on MAC pc

Tags: ruby, installation

I am a newbie to MAC environment .I  am working on MAC OSX(10.5.1).
I need to install ruby 1.8.7 on the MAC PC without disturbing the
already existing ruby 1.8.6
Can anybody please provide a step by step approach ?

Regards,
Sun

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to you, the use of [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com). Install ruby in your USER home.